# Wrong image loaded from the same file when the file is overwritten

Tags: android, file, imageview, overwrite

I'm having some issues saving an image file, updating it and loading it into an ImageView through Gilde library.

Basically I'm writing to the cache directoty a file named **tmp_photo.jpg**.
I overwrite this file so that I don't get multiple files that I need to cleanup in the future.

This first time everything is working fine and the correct image is displayed in the ImageView.
The second time, even though I've overwritten the file and a new image should be loaded, the old one is displayed in the ImageView.

This is how I display the image:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
 .load(filePath)
 .error(R.drawable.error_holder)
 .centerCrop()
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
 .into(ivDisplayPhoto);
```

If I navigate to that file with any file explorer application, the file is updated and I can actually see the new photo when opening the file. One thing that I noticed is that the thumbnail isn't updated, but I don't care about it because I don't use it directly.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening? Thank you.

LE:

I managed to avoid this with a little trick, but I don't think it is the best solution. I'm still looking for how to do this with Glide directly. Here is what I did now:

```
// Invalid what was previously shown in the ImageView
ivDisplayPhoto.setImageURI(null);
ivDisplayPhoto.invalidate();

// Hide the progress & display the image
UiUtils.crossFade(ivDisplayPhoto, imageProgress);

livecastCover.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ivDisplayPhoto.setImageURI(fileUri);
    }
});
```

I have used Uri directly, instead of String path.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding a signature to the cache when using Glide. An example that shows setting the signature to something based on the uri of the saved file works for me (yours will probably need to be something different):

```
                    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                            .load(storageReference)
                            .signature(new StringSignature(uri.toString()))
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .placeholder(placeHolder)
                            .into(imageView);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Timber.e(e);
                    }
```

Comment: Good idea to use signature, but if the uri doesn't change there is no way to identify it. Guess this is more of a use case problem than technical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific image cache library.
But most certainly, in addition to saving the image to the disk, it also keeps the image in memory.

It does that because it's faster to read in memory than on the disk, and there is a high chance that the newly loaded image will be re-use (example : when you scroll a list). And since you gave the same name/url, it think it's the same image.

So, you either need to clear/disable the memory cache (bad) or have a different name for the image.

EDIT : And why do you want to keep only one image in cache ? Glide will handle automatically the deletion of old files, that's the point of these libraries, to make your life super easy !

Comment: I tried to disable the cache with ".diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)" but this didn't solve the issue.

I am trying to reuse the same file to avoid having multiple files which will occupy space for nothing. 

The flow is for an camera application which should temporary hold that file until the user accepts it or dismisses it.

Comment: That would disable the disk cache, when I think the problem is the application memory cache.